# PrimeNG component inside PrimeNG component

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm currently working on a project, where I need 2 lists in between which I have to move items (from left to right and backwards). I found that `primeNG` has a component that does that for you (picklist). Additionally I need to add tabs to the left list (which is also a primeNG component called TabView). Is it possible to combine these two or do I need to write my own picklist component?
Below is the `html` code for implementing `picklist` component. Is it possible to access sourceHeader and turn it into tabs?
Thank you for any help.

```
<p-pickList [source]="sourceCars" [target]="targetCars" sourceHeader="Available" targetHeader="Selected" [responsive]="true" filterBy="brand" 
    dragdrop="true" dragdropScope="cars" sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by brand" targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by brand" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}">

<ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        <img src="assets/showcase/images/demo/car/{{car.brand}}.png" style="display:inline-block;margin:2px 0 2px 2px" width="48">
        <div style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{car.brand}} - {{car.year}} - {{car.color}}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: does anyone know how to do this?